# Maintain cell number with different sheet number when copying

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sheet with days of the month and multiple failure modes, all failure modes are exact copies over the 31 days of the month.

on my control sheet I want to reference the cell in which the total data for that day is located.

So I have for day

- `='1'D8` in cell C6 on main page,
- In cell C7 I want `='2'D8`
- in C8 I want `='3'D8` Etc.

I have about 30 odd failure modes, and inputting 30 x 30 cells by hand is going to take for ever, thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDIRECT()`, for your example:

`=INDIRECT("'" & ROW()-5 & "'D8")`